# How does one use a different LightSwitch database connection string per user and environment?

Tags: azure, tfs, connection-string, visual-studio-lightswitch

I develop software in a multi-programmer source controlled world (TFS).  Moreover, I have multiple environments (i.e. individual desktop developer machines, QA and production in the Azure cloud).  The problem is, I'm unsure as to the best way to use different database connection strings for each environment.  I realize that I can manually update the web.config for the Server project but that causes a clash when check-in occurs.  This is a pretty critical issue for our team, so any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks....

Comment: Do take a look at this blog post from Paraleap (makers of Azure Watch product): http://blog.paraleap.com/post/2011/09/13/Managing-environments-in-a-distributed-Azure-or-other-cloud-based-NET-solution. HTH.